# android is not working

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onload

greeting,I am developing one app where i am implementing load more on RecyclerView view by using interface.

But the problem is that it work fine for first time and after that mOnLoadMoreListener will be null,i dont know why mOnLoadMoreListener will null.

so it will not load next element

This is my code and my listener is as follows
OnLoadMoreListener.java

```
public interface OnLoadMoreListener {
    void onLoadMore();
}
```

The main problem is that at first time it load the data well. and when i scroll the list down and when i reach at last item it will load next data at first time but after that it doesnt work...

I checked  mOnLoadMoreListener it become null.

So please give a solution. i am getting irritated because of it.
Please help me.Solve this problem because it is important for me.i searched on internet but i didnt get any help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As I see, first time you create `adapter = new DataAdapter();` in `onCreate()` method and set `adapter.setOnLoadMoreListener(new OnLoadMoreListener())`. But later in `getProducts()` method you recreate adapter (check JsonArrayRequest->onResponse) and lose `OnLoadMoreListener`. So this is the problem I suppose.

Comment: so what should i do to remove the problem

Comment: @unknownapk I'm glad to help. So you can mark the answer as correct